# How do you relate the number densities of neutrinos and photons soon after the positron–electron annihilation?

Tags: cosmology, neutrinos, cosmological-inflation, cosmic-microwave-background

I found this equation:

$n_\nu = \frac{3}{4} \frac{g_\nu T_\nu^3}{g_\gamma T_\gamma^3} n_\gamma$

Where does it come from?